# Prevent angular-ui-router from re-loading ui-view on first page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

On the first hit to a page I want to send a fully rendered page back to the user. This works fine if javascript is disabled, but if javascript is enabled then angular-ui-router looks up the state and renders into ui-view on top of the existing content. Is there a way to disable this on the first page load somehow?

See this issue: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1807 which suggests using $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept(), but I can't find much documentation about using it and not sure how to intercept the first page load.

Comment: Check the link provided in the issue: https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider#methods_deferintercept . It even provides an example. Make sure you call that method during you are bootstrapping your app's config.

Comment: That's weird, I just see a blank page in Chrome (http://share.aidanlister.com/aYJx) which is why I was so confused.

Comment: How do you handle server side rendering?

Answer (score 7):

There's two parts: firstly you need to disable the router from kicking in on the first page load. This can be done like so:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // On the first page load disable ui-router so that
  // our server rendered page is not reloaded based on the window location.
  $urlRouterProvider.deferIntercept();
});
```

Secondly we need to set up the ui-view correctly: Dumping the server-rendered markup inside the ui-view causes issues weird behaviour with the first controller being run twice (see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1807), so we'll add our server rendered markup just after the ui-view div and hide the ui-view until there's a navigation event.

```
<div ng-controller="PropertyDetailCtrl">
  <div class="ng-cloak" ng-show="!isFirstPageLoad" ui-view></div>

  <div ng-show="isFirstPageLoad">
    (server rendered markup goes here)
  </div>
</div>
```

Now we need to set isFirstPageLoad in the $scope:

```
app.controller('PropertyDetailCtrl', function loader($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.isFirstPageLoad = true;

  $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading', function(event, viewConfig) {
    $scope.isFirstPageLoad = false;
  });
});
```

We've used ng-cloak to make sure that the page behaves perfectly if javascript is disabled, so now we've got a fully server side rendered first page load with all subsequent navigation handled by ui-router.

Comment: Have you figured out how to deal with going forth and back in history. If I browse to different states and then use the back button to go back to the page with isFirstPageLoad=true, then the static content is still there, but the dynamic state is loaded as well.

Comment: Honestly, I swapped from Angular to React and that fixed everything ...